# Secondary keywords for Material-UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I have a Material-UI Autocomplete-component in use. I give it a list of options that are objects like { label: "string", action: () => {}}. The autocomplete now takes into account every item in the list based on their label-value, that matches the given input in TextField. I would like to add a field to the option-objects, e.g. secondary: "label2", which would be taken into account in the Autocomplete as well, after all primary labels.

```js
<Autocomplete
    disablePortal
    popupIcon={false}
    autoHighlight={true}
    limitTags={7}
    onChange={onChange}
    ListboxProps={{ style: { minHeight: "300px", maxHeight: "300px" } }}
    noOptionsText="No commands found"
    open
    options={options.sort((a, b) => {
         const textA = a.label.toLowerCase()
         const textB = b.label.toLowerCase()
         return textA < textB ? -1 : textA > textB ? 1 : 0
    })}
    autoComplete={true}
    renderInput={(params) => {
    return <TextField {...params} autoFocus={true} placeholder="Enter a command" />
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Check the documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/  . getOptionLabel or renderOption may help you

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. With the [filterOptions-parameter](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#custom-filter:~:text=Custom%20filter,-The%20component%20exposes) in the Autocomplete-component it's quite easy to take the secondary keywords into account, with the stringify-function inside the createFilter-function that gets imported form Material-UI.